# Extract options from Javascript tree to insert into word document as a list

Tags: javascript, web, text, tree

First things first, I am not a developer or programmer! But I like to be able to use developer tools to make my working life more efficient, even if I don't fully understand what I'm doing!

Sometimes, I have to create a list in a Word document, from a website list, for other people to choose options without going to the website themselves. Using Firefox and Notepad++, I can do this for HTML dropdownlists.

But, how do I extract the text options from a Javascript tree? [Please see the link to the example tree image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfSps.png)

Comment: You will need to share the JavaScript code, and the tree structure .. Is it JSON?  Is it an associative array?  Without knowing even the names of the fields, you are going to get little to no help.  What you are asking is WAY to broad a question, with no specific details.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)